# Two near-identical forms functioning differently

Tags: forms, jquery, post, jquery-validate

I have two nearly identical forms on two different pages which take in a user's name and email address. When I press the submit button, both of them call a validator, which works correctly, and then both are supposed to make an Ajax call and display the results. At this point, one of them makes the call successfully, and the other simply refreshes the page. I'm not sure what the difference is that causes one to work successfully and the other to fail. With the one that works, I already had this problem once with the form that works, which was caused by me generating the form through javascript. I have no idea what is causing it now. Here is the inline code for the functioning one:

```
<!--// MODAL: INVITE //-->
<div id="inviteModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
   <div class="response"></div>
   <form id="inviteForm" >
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var invites = <?php echo $user->getInvitesLeft(); ?>;
   </script>
   </form>
</div>
```

Response is where it displays the response from the Ajax call. I have to generate the content later on using Javascript because I take different actions depending on the value of invites. I was originally generating the whole thing, but I found that I had to have the form tags in place to prevent the refreshing problem the first time. Here is the code that generates the form the user sees:

```
if(invites < 1){
        $("#inviteModal").html("You have no invites left. You can get more by increasing your score.");
    }
    else{
        $("#inviteForm").html("<h2>Please enter the specified information for the friend you wish to invite. </h2>"+
       "<p>First: <input type=\"text\" name=\"first\"></p>"+
       "<p>Last: <input type=\"text\" name=\"last\"></p>"+
       "<p>Email: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></p>"+
       "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Invite\"></p>");
    }
    $("#inviteModal").css('display', "block");
    $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
```

And here is the validator function:

```
$("#inviteForm").validate({
//Rules for invite validation
rules: {
            first: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
//Messages to print if validation fails
messages: {
            first: "Please provide your friend's name.",
            email: "We cannot contact your friend without a valid email address.",
        },
//What to do when validation succeeds
submitHandler: function(form) {
            //Form is valid, make Ajax call
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/invite/process',
            data: $("#inviteForm").serialize(),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data, textStatus ,XHR) {
                //alert(data);

                if(data.indexOf("Thank you") >= 0 ){
                    $("#inviteModal .response").text(data);
                    invites -=1;
                }
                else{
                    $("#inviteModal .response").text(data);
                }
            }
            }); //End ajax
        } //End submitHandler
}); //End validator
```

As I said, this one works perfectly fine. The only difference between this one and the one that refreshes is that the non-functioning one is on a page that you don't have to be logged in to see, and takes different actions depending on whether or not a user is logged in. Here is the inline code:

```
<!--// MODAL: INVITE //-->
<div id="inviteModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
<div class="response"></div>
<form id="inviteForm" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<?php 
if(!$user || $user == null){ //No user logged in, display invite request form instead 
   $loggedin = false;
}
else{ //Allow user to invite friends
   $loggedin = true; 
}  
?>
</form>
```

Here is the generation code, almost identical except for one extra if layer:

```
if(!loggedin){
        $("#inviteForm").html("<h2>Please enter the specified information to request an invitation. </h2>"+
           "<p>First: <input type=\"text\" name=\"first\"></p>"+
           "<p>Last: <input type=\"text\" name=\"last\"></p>"+
           "<p>Email: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></p>"+
           "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Invite\"></p>");
    }
else{
        invites = <?php echo $user->getInvitesLeft(); ?>;
        if(invites < 1){
            $("#inviteModal").html("You have no invites left. You can get more by increasing your score.");
        }
        else{
            $("#inviteForm").html("<h2>Please enter the specified information for the friend you wish to invite. </h2>"+
           "<p>First: <input type=\"text\" name=\"first\"></p>"+
           "<p>Last: <input type=\"text\" name=\"last\"></p>"+
           "<p>Email: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></p>"+
           "<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Invite\"></p>");
        }
    }
    $("#inviteModal").css('display', "block");
    $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
```

And here is the validator:

```
$("#inviteForm").validate({
//Rules for invite validation
rules: {
            first: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
//Messages to print if validation fails
messages: {
            first: "Please provide your friend's name.",
            email: "We cannot contact your friend without a valid email address.",
        },
//What to do when validation succeeds
submitHandler: function(form) {
            //Form is valid, make Ajax call
            if(loggedIn){   //They are inviting a friend
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/invite/process',
                    data: $("#inviteForm").serialize(),
                    datatype: "html",
                    success: function(data, textStatus ,XHR) {
                        //alert(data);

                        if(data.indexOf("Thank you") >= 0 ){
                            $("#inviteModal .response").text(data);
                            invites -=1;
                            //$("#overlay").css("display", "none");
                            //$("#inviteModal").fadeOut(5000);
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#inviteModal .response").text(data);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }); //End Ajax
            }
            else{ //They are requesting an invite for theirself
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/invite/request',
                    data: $("#inviteForm").serialize(),
                    datatype: "html",
                    success: function(data, textStatus ,XHR) {
                        //alert(data);

                        $("#inviteModal .response").text(data);

                        return false;
                    }
                }); //End ajax
            }
                            return false;
        } //End submitHandler
}); //End validate
```

Again almost identical except for one extra layer of if. So why would the bottom one refresh the page instead of making the Ajax call while the first one works perfectly fine?

Comment: if you comment that extra code in the error page, then is it working correctly as that of the previous one?

Comment: This has since been separated out into 2 hard coded modals and I'm simply using php to decide which one is used based on whether a user is logged in, so now I no longer have to dynamically generate the content of the form.

Answer (score 1):

how about commenting out those `return false` statement in the ajax success callback functions for the second one?